# troubles lining up my search box with a drop down list box

Tags: php, html, css

On the site I am developing (beta.btcbidder.com) I am trying to line up the search box and its category listing in the userbar at the top.

If you visit the page, you will see how the search box and categories do not quite line up right.

Here is the code:

```
<menu type="toolbar" id="userbar">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"><img align=left src="/media/images/logo.png" alt="BtcBidder.com" ></img></a>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>listings/">Listings</a>
            <menu id="listing-categories">
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>listings/all/">Browse All Listings&hellip;</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>listings/search/">Search Listings</a></li>
            </menu>
        </li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>account/">My Account</a>
            <menu id="account-menu">
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>account/balance/">My Balance</a></li>
                <li><hr /></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>account/my-bids/">My Bids</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>account/my-listings/">My Listings</a></li>
                <!--<li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>account/my-watchlist/">My Watchlist &mdash; Coming soon!</a></li>-->
                <li><hr /></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>account/messages/">Messages</a></li>
            </menu>
        </li>
        <!--THIS SECTION IS THE SEARCH BAR -->
        <!----------------------------------->
        <li>
            <form id="search" action="#" method="post">
                <input id="q" name="q" type="text" placeholder="search..." />
                <select id="q_category" name="q_category">
                    <option value="">All Categories&hellip;</option>
<?php 
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tbl_category ORDER BY parent_fk ASC, title ASC;');
    foreach($query->result() as $row) {
        $key = ($row->parent_fk == "")? $row->category_pk : $row->parent_fk;
        $search_categories[$key][] = $row;
    }

    foreach($search_categories as $key=>$val) {
        printf('                        <option value="%s">%s</option>' . "\n", $val[0]->slug,     $val[0]->title);
        if(count($val) > 1) {
            foreach($val as $categorykey=>$categorydata) {
                if($categorykey > 0) {
                    printf('                        <option value="%s">&nbsp;&nbsp;&            hellip;%s</option>' . "\n", $categorydata->slug, $categorydata->title);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
                </select>
                <input id="q_submit" name="q_submit" type="submit" value="Search &raquo;" />
            </form>
        </li>
        <!--THIS ENDS THE SEARCH BAR       -->
        <!----------------------------------->

<?php /*            <li><a href="">Administration</a>
                <menu id="administration-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Manage Disputes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Manage Listings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Manage Categories</a></li>
                    <li><hr /></li>
                    <li><a href="">Manage Users</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="">Banned Users List</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Manage Banned Wordlist</a></li>
                    <li><hr /></li>
                    <li><a href="">Ban this User</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Delete this Listing</a></li>
                </menu>
            </li>*/ ?>
            <li><a href="">Signup</a></li>
            <li class="right"><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>login/">Login</a></li>
<?php include(APPPATH . 'views/ticker.inc.php'); ?>
        </menu>
```

Comment: change the `line-height` on `#search`

Comment: I cannot see the problem on your site? I might be missing something, or you've used the advice of Josan Iracheta. If the latter is the case then please let us know.

Comment: sorry guys, I was taken away from this task for a few days. I'll review again and reply. @KIKOSoftware, what browser were you viewing with?

Comment: Firefox 31 on Windows 8.1. The search box and select list are vertically lined up perfectly, although a bit too low in my opinion. Your search form with id=search leaves 16 pixel of height voor the form elements, but they are 22 pixels high, and so don't really fit in that space. I think you need to reduce the padding of the form. (I'm leaving now, so I cannot read your response, or respond to it).